# How to store uint32_ts in an array of uint8_ts

Tags: c++

I have to serialize a bunch of `uint32_t` values into an array of `uint8_t`s. How do you do this in an portable efficient way?

Comment: You can't, since `u32_t` and `u8_t` are not standard types

Comment: Do you need to deal with endianness issues ?

Comment: @Quentin since it hase to work on platforms with different endianess presumably yes.

Comment: @TNA *on* different platforms or *between* different platforms ? The problem appears when the emitter and the receiver are of different endiannesses.

Comment: By the way: What's wrong with this question? 4 downvotes but noc solution and no explanation.

Comment: @Quentin not bettween

Comment: You can use the functions from the `htonl()` family from `arpa/inet.h` to tackle the endianess issues. Accessing the bytes is a simple cast then: `(uint8_t*)&value32;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable way to manipulate raw byte arrays is `std::memcpy` and `char` buffers.

```
uint32_t toBeSent = 42;
char buffer[sizeof toBeSent];

std::memcpy(&buffer, &toBeSent, sizeof toBeSent);
sendBuffer(buffer);

// ...

uint32_t toBeReceived;
char buffer[sizeof toBeReceived];

receiveBuffer(buffer);
std::memcpy(&toBeReceived, &buffer, sizeof toBeReceived);
```

Comment: Note that `char` is nowhere guaranteed to be of precisely 8 bits. It's perfectly valid for an implementation to have `char` and all integral types of the same width.

Comment: @skyking ergo there is no portable way to do this with `uint8_t` if `uint8_t` is not `char`. But there's a good chance OP actually wants `char`s.

Comment: @Quentin That's still not portable, because endianess is neglected in your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ see the comments under the question. I made sure that endianness was not an issue in OP's case (no cross-platform communication).

Answer (score 1):

While the `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` (standard C) are accessible via `cstdint`, there is no guarantee that they actually exists. The C standard says that they should be exactly that number of bits **if** they exist. For example they could be missing on 36-bit and other odd platform.

Apart from that it's just a matter of converting by arithmetic:

```
hi = (x >> 24) & 0xFF;
ji = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;
ko = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
lo = (x >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

and similarily the other way around:

```
x = (hi << 24ul) | (ji << 16ul) | (ko << 8ul) | (lo << 0ul);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer to take that into account. The real problem is of course that you're not guaranteed to be on a platform with these integer widths.